# Intel Edison Program Deleted After Power Off

Tags: arduino, intel-edison

I just bought a new Intel Edison and flashed the newest Yocto 3.0 image. I uploaded an Arduino program from the Arduino ide which just constantly prints out numbers to serial.

After uploading the code, it works. After I unplug it and plug it back in and wait 2 minutes for it to power on, I open the serial connection and the Edison does nothing like I never uploaded anything.

After some research I found it is a problem with the firmware version 2.5 so I tried 2.1. I tried 2.1 and it still doesn't work. Am I doing anything wrong?

I am using the mini-breakout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it works but you can still try following this [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/08/01/procedure-to-autostart-the-arduino-sketch-on-edison-0) on Intel's Developer Zone.